# Как скопировать строки из DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Создаю другой `DataGridView`, скопировал массив строк из одного, хочу добавить в другой. Ошибка, надо чтобы столбцы совпадали. Через цикл скопировал название и тип столбцов. Ошибка, такой столбец уже есть (тут уже возникло недоумение). Что только не перепробовал. И в `DataView` пытался превращать и в `DataTable`. В общем. Есть одна таблица, заполняемая так:

```
counterpartyListGV.ReadOnly = false;
MDM_DBDataSetTableAdapters.PERSONTableAdapter Ptb = new MDM_DBDataSetTableAdapters.PERSONTableAdapter();
Ptb.Fill(mainForm.MDM_DS.PERSON);                
var checkBoxColumn = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
checkBoxColumn.HeaderText = "";
checkBoxColumn.Name = "CheckBoxColumn";

checkBoxColumn.ReadOnly = false;
checkBoxColumn.FalseValue = false;
checkBoxColumn.TrueValue = true;
counterpartyListGV.Columns.Add(checkBoxColumn);
for (int i = 1; i < counterpartyListGV.Columns.Count; i++) counterpartyListGV.Columns[i].ReadOnly = true;
counterpartyListGV.DataSource = mainForm.MDM_DS.PERSON.DefaultView;
```

Нужно скопировать те строки, которые отмечены галочкой в первом (дополнительном) столбце.

**upd.**: Сейчас вот тоже пытаюсь вставить построчно те строки, что отмечины галкой в первом столбце.

```
DataGridView mergeRows = new DataGridView();
for (int i = 0; i < counterpartyListGV.Rows.Count; i++)
if (((DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)counterpartyListGV.Rows[i].Cells[0]).Value != null && (bool)((DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)counterpartyListGV.Rows[i].Cells[0]).Value)
{
     mergeRows.Rows.Add(counterpartyListGV.Rows[i].Cells);
}
```

Но так не работает (мол, нет столбцов в новом DataGridView). Пытаюсь добавить столбцы:

```
DataGridViewColumn[] a = new DataGridViewColumn[counterpartyListGV.Columns.Count];
counterpartyListGV.Columns.CopyTo(a, 0);
mergeRows.Columns.AddRange(a);
```

Говорит, что "Указанный столбец уже принадлежит к элементу управления DataGridView". Уфф.

Comment: Посмотри тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6336239/copy-datagridviews-rows-into-another-datagridview
Должно помочь, но, возможно, не самый быстрый способ, т.к. циклы используются.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Одно из основополагающих правил современной разработки - данные должны быть отделены от представления.

У вас данные хранятся в `DataTable` - вот с ним и нужно работать. А `DataGridView` - это представление - не трогаем его, просто используем привязку данных.

Я набросал полностью рабочий пример. Данные заносятся в `DataTable` в коде, а не из БД.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        DataGridView dataGridView1;
        DataGridView dataGridView2;
        DataTable dataTable;

        public Form1()
        {
            //InitializeComponent();
            Size = new Size(400, 400);

            dataGridView1 = new DataGridView { Parent = this, Dock = DockStyle.Top };
            dataGridView2 = new DataGridView { Parent = this, Dock = DockStyle.Bottom };

            // Здесь ваш код чтения данных из БД
            dataTable = new DataTable();
            dataTable.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
            dataTable.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            dataTable.Rows.Add(1, "Bob");
            dataTable.Rows.Add(2, "Alice");

            // Добавляем колонку в источник данных
            dataTable.Columns.Add("Check", typeof(bool));

            // Делаем привязку данных
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable;

            new Button { Parent = this, Top = dataGridView1.Bottom + 10, Text = "Copy" }
                .Click += ButtonCopy_Click;
        }

        private void ButtonCopy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Создаём вью            
            var dv = new DataView(dataTable);

            // Фильтруем данные во вью
            dv.RowFilter = "Check = true";

            // Делаем привязку данных
            dataGridView2.DataSource = dv;

            // Скрываем колонку, если не нужна
            dataGridView2.Columns["Check"].Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Обратите внимание, все манипуляции осуществляются непосредственно с источником данных - `DataTable`. Мы практически не касаемся `DataGridView`.

Answer (score 1):

Я решал подобную проблему следующим образом:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGrid.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
            row = (DataGridViewRow)dataGrid.Rows[i].Clone();
            int intColIndex = 0;
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dataGrid.Rows[i].Cells)
            {
                row.Cells[intColIndex].Value = cell.Value;
                intColIndex++;
            }
            DateTime end_date = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGrid.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value);
            int diff = (end_date - today).Days;
            if (diff > 20 || Convert.ToInt32(dataGrid.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value) != 0)
            {
                continue;
            }
            DeadLinesDataGridView.Rows.Add(row);
        }
```

Мне надо было скопировать в DeadLinesDataGridView все записи, у которых до завершения осталось < 20 дней.
Я копировал строку методом DataGridViewRow.Clone(), потом переносил все данные по ячейкам из одной строки в другую и вставлял в нужную таблицу.

Answer (score 1):

Не дождался ответа, пока так сделал (вроде работает) не знаю, как насчет оптимальности.

```
DataGridView mergeRows = new DataGridView();
foreach (DataGridViewColumn Col in counterpartyListGV.Columns)
    mergeRows.Columns.Add((DataGridViewColumn)Col.Clone());
for (int i = 0; i < counterpartyListGV.Rows.Count; i++)
    if (((DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)counterpartyListGV.Rows[i].Cells[0]).Value != null && (bool)((DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)counterpartyListGV.Rows[i].Cells[0]).Value)
    {
        DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)(counterpartyListGV.Rows[i]).Clone();
        for (int j = 0; j < counterpartyListGV.Rows[i].Cells.Count; j++) row.Cells[j].Value = counterpartyListGV.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value;
        mergeRows.Rows.Add(row);
    }
```

Comment: Ну по сути, тоже самое, что я предложил

Comment: Да, согласен, похоже. Просто вопрос оставил больше двух дней назад, а просмотры только сегодня пошли...

Answer (score 1):

Привет вот я так сделал

```
namespace DataGrid
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<Human> humans = new List<Human>();
        DataTable Table = new DataTable();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            humans = new List<Human>()
            {
                new Human(){ Name = "John", Age = 12},
                new Human(){ Name = "Alexis", Age = 13},
                new Human(){ Name = "Alura", Age = 21},
                new Human(){ Name = "Grey", Age = 7},
                new Human(){ Name = "Mike", Age = 12},
                new Human(){ Name = "Philip", Age = 12}
            };
            View.DataSource = humans;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Table.AsDataView();
            if(Table.Columns.Count == 0)
            {
                Table.Columns.Add("Имя", Type.GetType("System.String"));
                Table.Columns.Add("Возраст", Type.GetType("System.String"));
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < View.SelectedRows.Count; i++)
            {
                var values = new List<object>();
                for (int j = 0; j < View.SelectedRows[i].Cells.Count; j++)
                {
                    values.Add(View.SelectedRows[i].Cells[j].Value);
                }
                Table.Rows.Add(values.ToArray());
            }
            dataGridView1.DataSource = Table;
        }
    }
    class Human
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
}
```